# volume of a toric section

Tags: integration, volume

I'm trying to figure out how to compute the volume of the bottom part of a torus sliced by an oblique plane, which is neiter perpendicular nor parallel to the torus axis.

I've tried integration, but I can't find any straightforward way of doing it, but I'm sure there is !

thanks a lot for your help